# JavaScript - delete object properties in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is there a better / shorter method to delete properties from objects in an array of objects than the below example. I can use vanilla JS or lodash.

Exmaple function:

```
  function stripObjProps(arr) {
    let newArr = _.clone(arr);
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      delete newArr[i].isBounded;
      delete newArr[i].isDraggable;
      delete newArr[i].isResizable;
      delete newArr[i].maxH;
      delete newArr[i].maxW;
      delete newArr[i].minH;
      delete newArr[i].minW;
      delete newArr[i].resizeHandles;
      delete newArr[i].moved;
      delete newArr[i].static;
    }
    return newArr;
  }
```

Comment: `["isBounded","isDraggable","isResizable","maxH","maxW","minH","minW","resizeHandles","moved","static"].forEach(k => delete newArr[i][k])`

Comment: @Bravo `forEach` is missing the `index i` variable i guess

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli nope ... `i` comes from the for loop over the newLay array (whatever that is) the code I suggested is **inside** the for loop

Comment: I would probably map the array and rebuild the objects (destructure either the props you want or the props you don't want). Also you can use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) now for native deep cloning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways

```
function stripObjProps(arr) {
    let newArr = _.clone(arr);
    for (let i = 0; i < newLay.length; i += 1) {
        [
            "isBounded", 
            "isDraggable", 
            "isResizable", 
            "maxH", 
            "maxW", 
            "minH", 
            "minW", 
            "resizeHandles", 
            "moved", 
            "static"
        ].forEach(k => delete newArr[i][k]);
    }
}
```

or - assuming `newLay` is a typo

```
function stripObjProps(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => {
        let {
            isBounded,
            isDraggable,
            isResizable,
            maxH,
            maxW,
            minH,
            minW,
            resizeHandles,
            moved,
            static,
            ...ret
        } = item;
        return ret;
    });
}
```

NOTE: no need for `_.clone` in this second example, since you aren't doing a deep clone, map returns a new array with a new object (`...ret`)

However, I don't use lodash, so there may be an even better way with that *library*

Comment: @pilchard hmmm ... I think the second code would still produce a different result ... the original OP's code would mutate the objects in the original array, would it not? maybe not, I'm overthinking now!!!

Comment: If clone is indeed shallow, then yes, they should mutate the originals (probably an unwanted side effect?) heh.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) from Lodash to exclude properties:

```
function stripObjProps(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => _.omit(item, ['isBounded', 'isDraggable', 'isResizable', 'maxH', 'maxW', 'minH', 'minW', 'resizeHandles', 'moved', 'static']));
}

const newArray = stripObjProps(originalArray)
```

Additionally, you can use [`pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) instead of `omit`. In case of `pick` you specify only the properties which you want to keep.

Comment: I knew `lodash` would have to have something useful - If you're going to use lodash, you may as well read the documentation and use all of it :p

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove properties with `filter` and Object `entries` / `fromEntries`.

```js
const data = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }, 
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }, 
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
];

const excludeKeys = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

const exclude = (obj) => 
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key]) => !excludeKeys.includes(key)));
    
const result = data.map(exclude);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```